How do I implement flatMap for an object with a Function property?
import java.util.function.Function;

class FunctionCompose<T, R> {
    public final Function<T, R> function;

    public FunctionCompose(Function<T, R> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public <U> FunctionCompose<T, U> map(Function<? super R, ? extends U> mapper) {
        return new FunctionCompose<>(function.andThen(mapper));
    }

    //code flatMap

    public R apply(T smth) {
        return function.apply(smth);
    }
}

I am stuck at writing flatMap, where it is suppose to take in another Function which provides another FunctionCompose as an output. The code is suppose to work when
FunctionCompose of type <String, Integer> flatMap with (Integer -> FunctionCompose<Integer, Integer>)
Thanks in advance

If the result of flatMap itself needs to be FunctionCompose<Integer, Integer>, I don't think it's possible. That's because there is no way to let the Integer input of the result map back to a String for the original.
If the result of flatMap should be FunctionCompose<String, Integer>, then I think this should work:
public <U> FunctionCompose<T, U> flatMap(Function<? super R, FunctionCompose<? super R, ? extends U>> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    Function<T, U> mappingFunction = t -> {
        R value = function.apply(t);
        FunctionCompose<? super R, ? extends U> mappedCompose = mapper.apply(value);
        return mappedCompose.apply(value);
    };
    return new FunctionCompose<>(mappingFunction);
}

Or slightly shorter:
public <U> FunctionCompose<T, U> flatMap(Function<? super R, FunctionCompose<? super R, ? extends U>> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    return new FunctionCompose<>(function.andThen(r -> mapper.apply(r).apply(r)));
}

I didn't make it null safe in the results of the mapper, but that's not hard to add if needed.
